# Please help understanding following elisp code of origami package

Tags: code-folding

In file `origami.el` of package `origami` from MELPA is the function `origami-fold-node` and there is the following piece of code, which I do not understand:

```
(when (-some? (lambda (pair)
                  (let ((a (car pair))
                        (b (cadr pair)))
                      (when b ;for the odd numbered case - there may be a single item
                          ;; the < function doesn't support varargs
                          (or (>= (origami-fold-beg a) (origami-fold-end a))     ;; *1* clear
                              (>= (origami-fold-end a) (origami-fold-beg b))     ;; *2* ??
                              (>= (origami-fold-beg b) (origami-fold-end b)))))) ;; *3* clear
              (-partition-all-in-steps 2 1 sorted-children))
    (error "Tried to construct a node where the children overlap or are not distinct regions: %s"
           sorted-children))
```

In this piece of code happens a sort of range check (I think) and there are 3 points of failure, see comments with `*<N>*` at the end of those lines.

Case `*1*` and `*3*`are clear begin must be before end.

But case `*2*` I do not understand, why is this a failure?
If `beg a` is even bigger than `end b` everything is fine, because `a` wraps `b`. And then of course `end a` must be bigger than `beg b`.

Could someone please enlighten me?

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with elisp and is a good example of business/domain logic at work.

Comment: Does that mean this Question does not belong into emacs stackexchange?

Comment: The question is unclear. And the snippet is not self-contained. Please provide a recipe to provide the context (functions that are not defined in vanilla Emacs etc.).

Comment: The error message is "Tried to construct a node where the children overlap or are not distinct regions", so the logic makes sense -- if the end of 'a' is greater than the beginning of 'b' then, assuming 'a' begins before 'b', those two regions overlap.

Comment: No, this means that the `elisp` tag is misleading, it wouldn't matter what language this snippet is in as it's the logic puzzling you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the following overlays (assuming sorted originals, as indicated by the variable names in the actual code):

```
(beg a) (end a)
    v     v
    AAAAAAA
        BBBBBBBB
        ^      ^
    (beg b) (end b)
```

`(end a)` is greater than `(beg b)` and does therefore indicate an overlap. Overlapping folded regions don't make any sense. This is therefore an error.

Comment: Oh, you are correct, but if `AAA` wraps `BBB` this would be a wrong indicator?

Comment: I mean: if `AAA` wraps `BBB` this condition would be a bug?

Comment: Wrapping is seemingly not allowed, as the error says "Tried to construct a node where the children overlap **or are not distinct regions**".